# Prove that all proper subgroups of a group of order $8$ are commutative.

Tags: group-theory

> Prove that all proper subgroups of a group of order $8$ are
>   commutative.

Let $H$ be a subgroup of a group $G$. Then $o(H)\mid o(G)\implies o(H)=1,2,4$.
If $o(H)=1 $ or $2$, then $H$ is commutative. If $o(H)=4$, what can we say?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please [edit] the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck. Hint: your edit is the first of two easy steps. What can $H$ be?

Comment: What do you think about the question? Can you use any theorem? For example, if $H$ is a subgroup of this group, what can you say about its order?

Comment: All groups of order $1-5$ are commutative. This is well known.

Comment: Let $G$ be the cyclic group of order $8$. This is commutative and so all of its subgroups are commutative. This answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Lagrange theorem, the order of a proper subgroup of a group is a proper divisor of order of that group. That means, that proper subgroups of a group of order $8$ have order either 1 (the only group with such order is a trivial group), or $2$ (the only group with such order is $C_2$), or $4$ (the only groups with such order are $C_4$ and $C_2 \times C_2$). It is not hard to see that all aforementioned groups are abelian.